# Insert a space between a non-alphanumeric and alphanumeric char except specific char (Python)

Tags: python, regex, tokenize, arabic, diacritics

Is there any chance to exclude some of the unicode (non-alphanumeric) from being considered?
I'm tokenizing Arabic words which contains diacritics sometimes, that is considered as non-alphanumeric character but I don't want to remove them and I need to have a space between non-alphanumeric character (other than the diacritics) and alphanumeric.. and this is by using regex ? the unicode that I want to exclude which represent diacritics are as follow :u'\u064b', u'\u064c', u'\u064d', u'\u064e', u'\u064f', u'\u0650', u'\u0651', u'\u0652'

is that possible ?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Would you edit your question to include an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a custom alpha-numeric pattern for your purpose:

```
accents = [u'\u064b', u'\u064c', u'\u064d', u'\u064e', u'\u064f', u'\u0650', u'\u0651', u'\u0652']
alnum = r'([\w%s]+)' % re.escape(''.join(accents))
pattern = re.compile(alnum, re.UNICODE)
```

To find all tokens:

```
>>> test_str = "...foo" + ''.join(accents) + "...bar"
>>> test_str
'...fooًٌٍَُِّْ...bar'
>>> pattern.findall(test_str)
['fooًٌٍَُِّْ', 'bar']
>>> len(_)
2
```

Now to put a space between tokens and the rest:

```
>>> ' '.join(filter(None, pattern.split(test_str)))
'... fooًٌٍَُِّْ ... bar'
>>> len(_.split())
4
```

Comment: Wow! thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed.. highly appreciated, working perfectly